# Toggle behaviour based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The goal here is to make a page responsive and mobile friendly.

I show an invoice with all its details when on a desktop. But when the viewport is reduced, the details are hidden and can be toggled (hide/unhide) on clicking/tapping.

So I have a `trigger` and a `target` class.

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('.target').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

This works as expected if I add the `hide` class to `target` in my markup. But I cannot do that as they should appear unless the user views the page at a small screen. I can set `display: none` in the media queries but that hides target for good.

What property of the `target` element should I modify so that it hides itself when the screen size is reduced and I can toggle its view with the `hide` class?

Comment: Try to use [`resize()` handler](https://api.jquery.com/resize/). In this handler you can check windows sizes

Comment: In your media query, set `display:none;` and via JS when the screen width is equal to the desired width, do `.css({'display': 'block'})`

Comment: Try using `$('.target').toggle();` if all you want is to hide/show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Javascript solution would be to add a hook to `load` and `resize` event handlers that would check the screen width and add/remove the class accordingly.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    //Assuming you consider anything >= 1240 as desktop
    $('.target').toggleClass('hide', $(window).width() < 1240);
});
```

A `CSS` solution:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1240px) {
    .target {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1239px) {
    .target {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `display: none` results in me being unable to toggle its view with a click or tap. The target element is hidden as long as the css rule applies. Is there any other css solution that could be used here?

Comment: Well, you need to change your click handler a bit to make it work with the CSS I posted above. Let me add something in a few.

Answer (score 4):

This all depends on what you are doing:

You could use JavaScript to detect the width and add specfic classes on the toggle to display it.

```
$screenWidthCheck = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
if ($screenWidthCheck > 1280) {
    $("#page-content").addClass('active');
}
```

You could then add an even to it.

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    $screenWidthCheck = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    if ($screenWidthCheck > 1280) {
        $("#page-content").addClass('active');
    }
});
```